$\bmod \mathcal{C}$ Vietoris-Begle Theorem
I'm studying Miller Lectures on Algebraic Topology, and I'm stuck in Proposition 68.7:

Proposition 68.7 (Mod $\mathcal{C}$ Vietoris-Begle Theorem). Let $\pi: E \rightarrow B$ be a fibration such that $B$ and the fiber $F$ are path connected, and suppose $\pi_1(B)$ acts trivially on $H_*(F)$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a Serre ideal and suppose that $H_t(F) \in \mathcal{C}$ for all $t>0$. Then $\pi_*: H_n(E) \rightarrow H_n(B)$ is a $\bmod \mathcal{C}$ isomorphism for all $n$.

And this is their proof:

Proof. The universal coefficient theorem guarantees that $E_{s, t}^2=H_s\left(B ; H_t(F)\right) \in \mathcal{C}$ as long as $t>0$. The same is thus true of $E_{s, t}^r$ and hence of $E_{s, t}^{\infty}$, so the edge homomorphism $\pi_*: H_n(E) \rightarrow H_n(B)$ is a $\bmod \mathcal{C}$ isomorphism.

I understand that $E^{\infty}_{s,t} \in \mathcal{C}$ for every $t>0$, but why does this imply that $\pi_*: H_n(E) \rightarrow H_n(B)$ is a $\bmod \mathcal{C}$ isomorphism?

Since the notes link to you are quite brief on the properties of Serre classes, I'll try and be somewhat detailed. Recall that the edge homomorphism in question has the form
$$
    \pi_n\colon H_n(E) = F_n H_n(E) \twoheadrightarrow F_n H_n(E) / F_{n - 1} H_n(E) = E^\infty_{n, 0} \hookrightarrow E^n_{n, 0} \hookrightarrow \cdots \hookrightarrow E^2_{n, 0} = H_n(B)
$$
Thus, it suffices to show that the inclusions $E^k_{n, 0} \hookrightarrow E^{k - 1}_{n, 0}$ and the projection $F_n H_n(E) \twoheadrightarrow F_n H_n(E) / F_{n - 1} H_n(E)$ are isomorphisms mod $\mathcal{C}$. For the inclusions, $E^k_{n, 0}$ is the kernel of the differential $d^{k - 1}\colon E^{k - 1}_{n, 0} \to E^{k - 1}_{n + k - 1, k - 2}$ whose codomain lies in $\mathcal{C}$, so we have a short exact sequence
$$
    0 \to E^k_{n, 0} = \ker d^{k - 1} \hookrightarrow E^{k - 1}_{n, 0} \twoheadrightarrow E^{k - 1}_{n, 0} / \ker d^{k - 1} \cong \operatorname{img} d^{k - 1} \to 0
$$
As $\operatorname{img} d^{k - 1} \subseteq E^{k - 1}_{n + k - 1, k - 2}$ is a subgroup of a group in $\mathcal{C}$, we conclude that the map at the left, which is the one we're interested in, is a mod $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism. For the projection, note that $F_0 H_n(E) = E^\infty_{0, n}$ lies in $\mathcal{C}$, so we can mount an induction: In the short exact sequences
$$
    0 \to F_k H_n(E) \hookrightarrow F_{k + 1} H_n(E) \twoheadrightarrow F_{k + 1} H_n(E) / F_k H_n(E) = E^\infty_{k + 1, n - k - 1} \to 0
$$
the right hand term lies in $\mathcal{C}$ for all $k < n$, hence so does the middle term if we can show the left one does, too, and the basis for this is the case $k = 0$. But this in particular implies that $F_n H_n(E) \twoheadrightarrow F_n H_n(E) / F_{n - 1} H_n(E)$ is a mod $\mathcal{C}$ isomorphism and we're done.

Thank you! I think that in the fourth line from the bottom you meant $E^{\infty}{k+1,n-k-1}$ intead of $E^{\infty}{n-k,k}$. So this term lies in $\mathcal{C}$ for all $k<n-1$.

@marc You're right, I got my indices mixed up.
